# Why does the Jquery alertmessage not show up?

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a Arduino and ESP8266 project.
I send a request with the clicked button, then Arduino generate a response for the get request but the alertmessage does not show up.
I want "hupppaaa" in the alertmessage

This is my generated response. (is this a correct response?)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 8
Connection: close

hupppaaa
```

This is the request Jquery code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".led").click(function(){
        var p = $(this).attr('id'); // get id value (i.e. pin13, pin12, or pin11)
        // send HTTP GET request to the IP address with the parameter "pin" and value "p", then execute the function
        $.get("http://192.168.0.150:80/", {pin:p}, function(data, status){
            alert(" Data Loaded: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        }); // execute get request
    });
});
```

Comment: Success callback should be wrap inside the .success method of $.get method

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should do like this with your $.get call

```
$.get( "http://192.168.0.150:80/", {pin:p} )
  .done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
  });
```

Comment: That's exactly the same thing OP does, just using a different way of specifying the callback.